# Open a PDF in browser disable the embedded Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, pdf, wicket

I created a wicket page which allow to the user to open PDF files. These PDF files are forms, which the user fill and send back. There is also Javascript which is used to automatically fill some fields.

The file is correctly open in the browser but there is a problem: Javascript is disabled and I don't know why. Is it normal? Is it for security reason?

When I download the file and open in Acrobat Reader, it works correctly.
I also disabled the option in Acrobat Reader to force the plugin to be used in place of the default reader of the browser. It works only in Firefox.

Is it possible to activate Javascript?
If not, is it possible to open automatically Adobe Reader?
I prefer not to save directly the file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about smartforms, you have to enable JavaScript in Acrobat. It has to be similar in browser or standalone. Also there can be many security reasons in different browsers due to enable/disable JS itself. One of the common reason is XSS voluentabirity. Also you have to know if the browser or its plugin supports JS. Not all browsers use Acrobat reader as well. However see http://www.smartforms.business.gov.au/DeveloperResources/Documents/JavaScript_Instructions.pdf how to enable JS in Acrobat Reader.

Generaly I do not recommend you to use PDF forms instead of HTML forms.

Comment: Adobe Reader is not the problem, it works when the file is downloaded or with the plugin. The problem is the browser's reader (like pdf.js).

Comment: you can't influence how the user set up his browser settings regarding handling pdf files